# How do I return a null value for a negative number?

Tags: sql-server, calculation, nullif

I am trying to perform additional aggregated calculations on a field that I created and because some values are negative, it is messing with the averages. If the values were to be `0`, it would also mess with the averages so it's important that these negative values are treated as `NULL`.

I think that I will probably need the `NULLIF` calculation on top of my existing query, but the syntax doesn't seem to accept `<0` and I can't find anywhere what the proper syntax would be.

```
SELECT
NULLIF(DATEDIFF(day,deposit_date,acceptance_date),<0) AS 'Days until Acceptance'
FROM data
```

Comment: Use the CASE statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested above, try:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(day,deposit_date,[acceptance date]) < 0 THEN NULL
        ELSE DATEDIFF(day,deposit_date,[acceptance date])
    END AS [Days until Acceptance]
FROM data
```

Also, some of your names do not meet the SQL syntax requirements so these have been changed in my answer.